# How do I get down equal to false when my player is going up?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want it so that when I press space I go up, and when I press space again, I go down etc...

```
public class PlayerMov : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool up;
    public bool down;

    public float moveSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        down = true;
        moveSpeed = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (up == true)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (down == true)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.down * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space") && up == true)
        {
            down = true;
            up = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("space") && down == true)
        {
            down = false;
            up = true;
        }

        if (down == true && up == true)
        {
            down = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I get it working for the first 2 space presses, but after that it just keeps on going up. Thank you for the help :) Also I'm a beginner in Unity if you couldn't tell..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with down = true and you always have either down or up true, never both, so you only need one:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        down = !down;
    }
    Vector3 direction = (down == true) ? Vector3.down : Vector3.up;
    transform.position += direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Anytime you press Space, it swap the boolean to its opposite. Also, the GetKey is now GetKeyDown so it only happen once instead of many frames in a row.

Answer (score 0):

**You actually don't need 2 variables at all. You can simplify all your code to this:**

```
public class PlayerMov : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool down = true;
    public float moveSpeed = 1;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            down = !down;
        }
        Vector3 directionVector = (down == true) ? Vector3.down : Vector3.up;
        transform.position += directionVector * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

---

But if you still for some reason want to keep it your way - you need to do it like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("space"))
    {
        if (up == true)
        {
            down = true;
            up = false;
        }
        else if (down == true)
        {
            down = false;
            up = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Also this part doesn't make any sense, it's doing nothing at all :))

```
    if (down == true && up == true)
    {
        down = true;
    }
```